# ZXing recognizes alphabetical Code 128 as UPC E

Tags: zxing.net

I generate a Code 128-Barcode with alphabetical data with Dymo Labelprinter. Dymo calls the Type "Code128Auto".

Recognition with Zbar works fine.

But ZXing regognizes "UG18/04/10363" as "UPC E" with the Text "06118745".

I tried to force Code128, but had no success.

```
ZXing.OneD.Code128Reader
```

and

```
List<BarcodeFormat> formats = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
formats.Add(BarcodeFormat.CODE_128);
hints.Add(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, formats);
```

[Sample Barcode Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1LbU.png)

Comment: Please provide a sample image of the generated code 128 barcode.

Comment: I added a sample image.

Comment: It works like a charm for me. I tried to decode the image with the current version of the WinForms demo of ZXing.Net. The result is: Code 128 - UG18/04/10363.